# Multiply extended magnitude - encountered a notion barrier while reading the work of Riemann

Tags: geometry, math-history

everybody!
I graduated with a degree in mathematics but switched careers and work as a software developer since then. I still have to satisfy that itch from time to time and refresh some long lost knowledge of mine or to get into a field I have neglected previously.

So I've picked up the talk *"On the Hypotheses which lie at the Bases of Geometry"* by Riemann but was immediately hit by a notion barrier. The cornerstone of the talk is the notion in the title of this post I have no idea what it means. To give a context, the first sentence using this term reads

*"The reason of this is doubtless that the general notion of **multiply extended magnitudes** (in which space-magnitudes are included) remained entirely unworked."*

I know (hopefully) the meanings of the individual words but the meaning still eludes me. If I'm not mistaken the word *magnitude* can be used in a very general meaning of a value (whatever that means) of a quantity (whatever that is). Like in

*"As Kepler demonstrated, the non-uniform elliptical planetary orbit defines the magnitude of action within an orbit, as equal areas, rather than the arbitrary mathematical magnitudes of equal arcs or equal angles."*

And if I'm not mistaken, the word magnitude is also often a synonym for a vector.

There is also the sentence *"... space is only a particular case of a **triply extended magnitude**."* hinting on the meaning having something to do with dimension.

Can anybody help me here, please?

Comment: We may say that Riemann's approach starts from the difficulty to "elucidate" the notion of *space*: we may note that in Euclid's *Elements* there is no def (nor the term) of "space". So, to say that *geometry* is "the science of space" is quite unsatisfactory.

Comment: According to R, we have to start from the basic notion of *magnitude* (quantity?) and (assuming that we have a more clear understanding of it that the notion of space...) and more generally of multi-dimensional magnitude:the sort of object that we can describe with coordinates. These objects are *multiply extended magnitudes*, of which the space of traditional geometry is an example with dimension=3.

Comment: I think the "$n$-ply extended magnitude" is just referring to the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) on a $n$-dimensional vector space; "extended" as in extension from the notion of magnitude/norm on a one-dimensional vector space like $\Bbb R$. It seems Riemann is saying that space (without the temporal dimension) is just a particular case of $\Bbb R^3$ equipped with some norm $||\cdot||$ (the usual norm being the one induced from the Euclidean metric, $||\cdot||_2$). Also, magnitude is not a synonym for vector. Simply put, magnitude is some scalar measure of a vector.